# How to dispatch from view to controller in Sencha Touch2 with Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

My View (MyFormPanel)

```
var controllers = Ext.define("MyApp.controller.formcontroller", {
    extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
    config: {
        refs: {
            username: "username"

 },
},
launch: function () {
     alert('Controller launched');

    },
    init: function () {
         alert('Controller init');
    },
myaction : function (options) {
    alert('options');
      var username = options.username;
      this.render ({
        xtype: 'MyATM',
        username: username})}
});
var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    scrollable: 'vertical',
    layout: {
        align: 'center',
        type: 'vbox'
    },
    items: [
            {
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                docked: 'top',
                title: 'Login Form'
            },
            {
        xtype: 'fieldset',
        items: [  
                {  
                    xtype: 'fieldset',   
                    title:'Enter user name & password',  
                    defaults: {  
                        required: true,  
                        labelAlign: 'left',  
                        labelWidth: '50%'  
                    },  
                    items: [  
                    {  
                        xtype: 'textfield',  
                        name : 'username',  
                        label: 'User Name', 
                        allowBlank:false,
                        useClearIcon: true  
                    }, {  
                        xtype: 'passwordfield',  
                        name : 'password',  
                        label: 'Password', 
                        allowBlank:false,
                        useClearIcon: false  
                    }, 
                    {
                        xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                        required:false,
                        id: 'RememberMe',
                        name: 'RememberMe',
                        label: 'Remember Me',
                        labelWidth: '50%'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            ui: 'confirm-round',
                            text: 'Log In' , 
                                handler: function() {
                                    //Ext.Msg.alert('Form Values', JSON.stringify(formPanel.getValues(), null, 2));

                                    Ext.ControllerManager.get('formcontroller').ControllerMethod({myaction: myaction});

                                }
                        }

                    ]  
                }],  
    }]
});

formPanel.add({
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    docked: 'bottom',
    layout: { pack: 'center' },

});
```

My controller (FormController)

```
    Ext.define("MyApp.controller.formcontroller", {
    extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
    config: {
        refs: {
            username: "username"

 },
},
launch: function () {
     alert('Controller launched');

    },
    init: function () {
         alert('Controller init');
    },
myaction : function (options) {
    alert('options');
      var username = options.username;
      this.render ({
        xtype: 'MyATM',
        username: username})}
});
```

I am using Sencha touch2 with Phonegap 1.4 on android 2.3. When i try to move view to controller on Login button click on handler function to invoke controller , i am getting error , Ext.dispatch is not defined as function . 
Tell me the actual way how to move view to controller  and vice versa. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Ext.dispatch` is not the recommended way to use in Sencha Touch 2. It might be removed...

Anyway, the best way to listen to & handle events on your views from controllers is:

```
Ext.define("MyApp.controller.formcontroller", {
extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
config: {
  refs: {
    loginButton: "#login-button" // set an id for your login button and this ref works
  },
  control: {
    loginButton: {
      tap: 'handleLogin',
    }
  handle_login: function(){whatever you want to do here}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And in Architect...
a. you go to the button's config, and 
b. search for Event Handlers, and 
c. you press the [+] button on the right.
d. Add a "basic handler"
e. Choose the TAP event
f. Give it a name (onButtonSendTap or whatever)
g. press DONE
h. right mouse
i. Convert to action
j. Choose [New Controller]  or an existing controller
k. If you chose new controller give it a name
and voilla, you have your handler in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

And in Architect...

a. you go to the button's config, and

b. search for Event Bindings, and

c. you press the [+] button on the right.

d. Add a "basic handler"

e. Choose the TAP event

f. Give it a name (onButtonSendTap or whatever)

g. press DONE

h. right mouse

i. Convert to action

j. Choose [New Controller]  or an existing controller

k. If you chose new controller give it a name
and voilla, you have your handler in the controller.